# Authenticate a 3rd party credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I want to store user's 3rd party credentials. Example:
 `email (ex: xxx@domain.com ), password and domain (ex: 'domain.com')`.

Is there any possible way to check if user's entered credentials of a third party website are correct?

Is there any API or gem to authenticate the credentials from our rails application?

Thanks in advance.